# Running mathematica from terminal

Tags: scripting

I was looking information about how to run a mathematical script from shell in a remote cluster. Normally, I used this command:

```
math <file.m> file.out&
```

And I wanted to learn more about this form to run the scripts. But I have not found information about this command. All I have found is about WolframScript and I don't understand what is the relationship between the command I commonly use and the commands of the WolframScript information.

What are they about (WolframScript)? What are the relationship and differences between these commands (WolframScript) and this command (before write)?. Why these commands (WolframScript) print the outputs in the shell and not in and .out file like the other command?

Comment: Think of wolframscript like Python, except that to run a file you need the `-f` flag